# On Android Studio 1.3, NDK support not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have upgraded the Android Studio to 1.3, about which they say they have added Native development support. But I found no change regarding NDK. :/
Any help?

Comment: [reposting is bad, m'kay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666579/android-studio-1-3-ndk-support-not-working) => [img](http://selvin.pl/repost1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not available yet.

"As announced at Google I/O, Android Studio 1.3 will include C/C++ support as well, but that is not included in the first couple of preview builds."

Source: 
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio13preview1available

Answer (score 1):

It is now available : http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiowithandroidndkpreviewsupportavailable

But you'll have to use the experimental gradle android plugin and gradle 2.5.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental